# Query form 2 columns, but pull data from the other corresponding column

Tags: sql

Edited:

Below is the query I've been able to make work...some what.  and to clarify, table with multiple columns, but need to query 2 of the columns, but need as single column.  Also. I really want the opposite column of the 2 I want to query.  if column a = user# I want the data in column b.  and vise-versa.

below is what I have and it does work, but I have 2 errors.

mysqli::stat(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/.......    and     Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset

Heres the code;

---

$db    = $this->getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

```
        // Select the required fields from the table.
        $query->select('d.*, uida AS contact ');

        $query->from('`#__user_memberlinks` AS d');

        $query->where('d.uidb =' . $userID);
        $query->where('d.usera = 1')->andWHERE ('d.userb = 1');


    // Join over the users for the checked out user.
    $query->select('uc.name AS uEditor');
    $query->join('LEFT', '#__users AS uc ON uc.id=d.checked_out');

    // Join over the created by field 'created_by'
    $query->join('LEFT', '#__users AS created_by ON created_by.id = d.created_by');

    // Join over the created by field 'modified_by'
    $query->join('LEFT', '#__users AS modified_by ON modified_by.id = d.modified_by');







         $db    = $this->getDbo();
        $query2 = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Select the required fields from the table.
        $query2->select('b.*, uidb AS contact');

        $query2->from('`#__user_memberlinks` AS b');

        $query2->where('b.uida =' . $userID);
        $query2->where('b.usera = 1')->andWHERE ('b.userb = 1');


    // Join over the users for the checked out user.
    $query2->select('uc.name AS uEditor');
    $query2->join('LEFT', '#__users AS uc ON uc.id= b.checked_out');

    // Join over the created by field 'created_by'
    $query2->join('LEFT', '#__users AS created_by ON created_by.id = b.created_by');

    // Join over the created by field 'modified_by'
    $query2->join('LEFT', '#__users AS modified_by ON modified_by.id = b.modified_by');


     $query->union($query2);
```

---

Thank you

Org. Post left for history

I have 2 columns in a table as such;

| Col A | Col B | UA | UB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 222 | 1 | 1 |
| 222 | 333 | 1 | 1 |
| 222 | 444 | 1 | 1 |
| 111 | 333 | 1 | 1 |
| 555 | 222 | 1 | 1 |

(probably messed up the table description, but)

Anyway, I want to query columns `A` and `B`, for say `222`  but pull the corresponding data from the other column.  A contact link, where one or the other members send the request and the other agrees, hence the 1 and 1 in columns `UA`, `UB`.  But I need the corresponding column to join the other users information on, so I can be displayed in a list of contacts.

I can do a simple query to pull each row where a users # is, but can't figure out how to get the other user as the actual data I want.

Hope that makes sense.

Thank you

Comment: Please post your current attempt and desired output for this sample data

Comment: You wrote _I have 2 columns in a table_  and posted table with 4 columns, did you?

Comment: astentx,  I have a current query that results in 0 returned rows,  I've messed with it several ways, but let me see if I can get a reasonable failed attempt to to show,

Comment: Alexey, yes sorry, poorly defined.  I need to query from 2 of the 4 columns.....Col A and Col B

Comment: `mysqli` is contained in the question, but you have only tagged "sql" (which is almost useless if you want a solution in the syntax that you need) - please **always** include the **actual dbms** as a tag. (Look for the "edit tags" link.)

Answer (score 0):

Your basic approach should be to flatten out your data so you can treat it like a normal query. You don't specify a RDBMS, but this works for SQL-Server

```
--Set up sample data
;with cteTabA as ( 
    SELECT * FROM ( VALUES 
        ('111', '222', '1', '2')
        , ('222', '333', '11', '21')
        , ('222', '444', '12', '22')
        , ('111', '333', '13', '33')
        , ('555', '222', '14', '41')
    ) as TabA(ColA, ColB, UA, UB) 
) SELECT * 
INTO #Sample
FROM cteTabA

--SELECT * FROM #Sample --Display test data
--Set up what we're looking for
DECLARE @LookFor char(3) = '222';

--Solution - flatten the table, but log where the ID came from
with cteFlat as (
    SELECT ColA as ID, UB as Opposite, 'A' as MatchCol
    FROM #Sample
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ColB as ID, UA as Opposite, 'B' as MatchCol
    FROM #Sample
)--Now just search for it
SELECT * FROM cteFlat as F 
WHERE ID = @LookFor 

--Clean up 
DROP TABLE #Sample
```

Output:

| ID | Opposite | MatchCol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | 21 | A |
| 222 | 22 | A |
| 222 | 1 | B |
| 222 | 14 | B |

Answer (score 0):

Follow Up;

The above Union Code does work.

The unserialized error is caused by Joomla's Debugging function, and does not show in the view if debugging is off.  Unsure why, or if its even an issue, since it does retrieve the data correctly.  If I understood correctly, Joomla has a way to deal with the unserialized data.

The "mysqli::stat(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/....... "  Error, went away by changing the server, database type to MySQL(PDO).  Guessing MySQLi doesnt handle the Union Query well.  The error did appear to come from the file located in libraries/jommla/database/driver/mysqli...

Thank you for the help all!